したんだ？Colloquial?
Is "shitanda" a colloquial form of suru?

No. It's the past tense of する with an abbreviated form of the "explanatory の". Try looking up this phrase.

No, したんだ is not a colloquial equivalent of する. First, した is the past form of する, so the tense is different. Second, したんだ has んだ, which is an explanatory-の followed by the copula だ.
This んだ is a difficult topic, and it's impossible to explain it in a single paragraph. For details, look up "explanatory の" or read these questions:

What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?
How is the "のです" working here?

